# why there is a small imaginary part

Tags: numerics, complex

I encountered a problem. I have a eigenvector `eigvsI[1]`

```
eigvsI[1]={0.0161028 - 0.0119647 I, 0.111551 - 0.0828846 I, 0.20484 - 0.1522 I, 
0.249467 - 0.185359 I, 0.28268 - 0.210037 I, 
0.301895 - 0.224314 I, -0.190871 + 0.141821 I, -0.271275 + 
0.201562 I, -0.244686 + 0.181807 I, -0.204743 + 
0.152128 I, -0.148422 + 0.11028 I, -0.0281275 + 0.0208993 I}
```

and a hermite matrix `hI[1]`

```
    hI[1]={{0, Sqrt[5]/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[5]/2, 0, Sqrt[2],
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, Sqrt[2], 0, 3/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0}, {0, 0, 3/2, 0, Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, Sqrt[
2], 0, Sqrt[5]/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[5]/2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[5]/2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[5]/2, 0, Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
Sqrt[2], 0, 3/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3/2, 0, Sqrt[2], 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[2], 0, Sqrt[5]/2}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[5]/2, 0}}
```

theoretically

```
Conjugate[eigvsI[1]].hI[1].eigvsI[1]
```

should be Real number. But *MMA* gives

```
-0.253172 - 8.00544*10^-18 I
```

where does this small imaginary part come from?

On the other hand,

```
Conjugate[eigvsI[1]].eigvsI[1]
```

gives perfect zero imaginary part

```
0.811081 + 0. I
```

Comment: Calculating eigenvalues involves factoring a large polynomial (the characteristic polynomial) and routines for factoring often "miss" by small amounts, causing small imaginary parts. I would just use `Chop` to remove the bear-zero parts.

Comment: @bills it's not the problem of calculating eigenvalues.

Comment: See this for a discussion of machine precision arithmetic in Mathematica: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html

Comment: @bills thank you bill s. OK, I understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The numbers you have, like `0.0161028 - 0.0119647 I` are floating point (machine precision) numbers. Whenever you do calculations with floating point numbers, you will get roundoff errors. Note that you appear to have 7 or 8 digits of accuracy in the numbers. The "error" in the imaginary part is in the 18th decimal place. This is roundoff error. See this for a discussion of [machine precision arithmetic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html) in Mathematica. The simplest way to remove such round-off errors is to use `Chop`, which replaces approximate real numbers that are close to zero with the exact number `0`. This effectively removes the imaginary part from a number like  `-0.253172 - 8.00544*10^-18 I`.

Comment: If OP absolutely doesn't want to use `Chop[]`: `Re[eigvsI[1]].hI[1].Re[eigvsI[1]] + Im[eigvsI[1]].hI[1].Im[eigvsI[1]]`.

Comment: @bill s Is there a way to apply `Chop` to intermediate results of iterative processes such as `NDSolve`?