# Unexpected complex roots from solving a cubic

Tags: equation-solving

I am new to *Mathematica* and there is a behavior that I don't understand. When I insert the code:

```
Solve[-(x - 2)^3 + 10 x - 10 == 0, x]
```

I obtain:

> ```
> {{x -> 2 + (2 5^(2/3))/(3 (9 + I Sqrt[39]))^(1/3) + (5 (9 + I Sqrt[39]))^(1/3)/3^(2/3)},  
> {x -> 2 - (5^(2/3) (1 + I Sqrt[3]))/  
>   (3 (9 + I Sqrt[39]))^(1/3) - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (5 (9 + I Sqrt[39]))^(1/3))/(2 3^(2/3))},  
> {x ->  2 - (5^(2/3) (1 - I Sqrt[3]))/
>   (3 (9 + I Sqrt[39]))^(1/3) - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (5 (9 + I Sqrt[39]))^(1/3))/(2 3^(2/3))}}
> ```

These are complex roots, but this polynomial has real roots, that in fact I can correctly find when I use Root. Why are this complex roots being displayed? Are these supposed to be approximations?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the answer, now I understand better the underlying process and that Solve is in fact finding exact solutions. The "approximate zero" in the imaginary component comes from the numerical solution to the exact root, not from Solve.

It can removed by using `Chop` as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24783/why-there-is-a-small-imaginary-part).

Comment: It's using radicals ...

Comment: You can find a bit of related info on this in the `ToRadicals` doc page.

Comment: These are not complex roots. For why they are given in a form that uses sqrt(-1), look up "casus irreducibilis".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solve - strange results when numericalized**

You need to be aware of, when solving cubical polynomials and the polynomial has three roots and does not factor, the answer returned by Mathematica will contain, when numericalized, a term like *verySmallNumber* *I.

In your case you could increase the precision:

```
Solve[-(x - 2)^3 + 10 x - 10 == 0, x] // N[#, 22] &

==> {{x->5.577089445136461440525+0.*10^-22 I},
     {x->-0.4236221399906988397916+0.*10^-23 I},
     {x->0.8465326948542373992666+0.*10^-23 I}}
```

which is in fact a *zero with finite accuracy* * I.

*NRoots* gives in this case purely real solutions:

```
NRoots[-(x - 2)^3 + 10 x - 10 == 0, x]

==> x == -0.423622 || x == 0.846533 || x == 5.57709
```

In Mathematica irreducible higher order polynomials will be solved for in *Root*-objects.

**Edit 1**

Let's spin that further. Let's just take the first root of your solution:

```
root1=2+(2 5^(2/3))/(3 (9+I Sqrt[39]))^(1/3)+(5 (9+I Sqrt[39]))^(1/3)/3^(2/3);
```

If we add now an approximate real  zero we will get a result in approximate real part:

```
root1 + 0.

==> 5.57709 -1.66533*10^-16
```

Which is one of the roots and a second part acting as *approximative zero*.

Comment: Well, `root1 + 0.` is no different from `root1 // N` that you did earlier :)

Comment: i know. i wanted to show how to deal with factors of the form "very small number" * I ...

Comment: I found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24783/why-there-is-a-small-imaginary-part)

how to remove the approximate zero using ``Chop``

Answer (score 7):

As belisarius notes, the result is using radicals. Using `FullSimplify` or `Cubics -> False` gives you `Root` objects, which are just as exact and equivalent, but again, not exactly what you need (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13768/5) by Artes for more on how to work with them).

In this case, you can use `ComplexExpand` to get a purely real solution:

```
Solve[-(x - 2)^3 + 10 x - 10 == 0, x] // ComplexExpand
```

[image]

Comment: Good complement to the answer. I would upvote it if I had enough reputation :-(